# quiero realizar una condicion de comparacion en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

el problema que tengo es que quiero comparar esos datos dependiendo el que me retorne quiero mostrar el resultado en mi vista este es el error que me tira  Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

```
$estado_civil = \DB::table('empleado')
            ->select('empleado.estado_civil','empleado.id')->where('empleado.id', '=', $id)->pluck('estado_civil');


        if ($estado_civil == 3){
            $estado_civil_empleado='soltero';
        }elseif ($estado_civil == 4){
            $estado_civil_empleado='casado';
        }
        elseif ($estado_civil == 5){
            $estado_civil_empleado='viudo';
        }

        dd($estado_civil_empleado);






//          dd($nivel_academico);
        return \View::make('empleado_consultar', compact('pais', 'nivel_academico', 'titulo_obtenido'))->with([
            'empleado' => $empleado,
        ]);

    }
```

en esta parte lo muestro lo intente hacer de esta forma pero no se como comparar mas datos aqui en mi vista entonces se me ocurrio hacerlo en mi controlador
 
                                
                                    Estado civil

```
             <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('certificado', 'Estado Civil:', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                {!! Form::text('certificado',$empleado->estado_civil==3?'soltero':'casado', $value = null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el certificado']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: ¿En dónde aparece el error?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu consulta está devolviendo una colección pero la quieres comparar a un integer. Prueba agregar `->first()` para que te devuelva un objeto, o en este caso, un `integer` si el campo `estado_civil` es `integer`, pues haces `->pluck('estado_civil')`:

```
$estado_civil = \DB::table('empleado')
            ->select('empleado.estado_civil','empleado.id')
            ->where('empleado.id', '=', $id)
            ->pluck('estado_civil')
            ->first();
```